# Dynamic programming-- min distance path --When to use return Integer.MAX_VALUE and return 0

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

I was practising a program to find minimum distance to last element (2,2) of  a 3 X 3 matrix.

```
static int minCost(int cost[][], int m,int n)
{
    if (n < 0 || m < 0)
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    else if (m == 0 && n == 0)
        return cost[m][n];
    else
        return cost[m][n] +
            min( minCost(cost, m-1, n-1),
                minCost(cost, m-1, n),
                minCost(cost, m, n-1) );
}
```

this gives correct answer 8, but, if i use `return 0;` instead of `return Integer.MAX_VALUE;` i get result as 7.(`return 0; \\gives answer as 7`
`return 1;//returning >0 values gives correct answer and <0(like -1-->gives 6,-2 -->gives 5 etc )`My driver code is

```
    public static void main(String args[])
{
    
    int cost[][] = { {1, 2, 3},
                    {4, 8, 2},
                    {1, 5, 3} };
                                
    System.out.print(minCost(cost, 2, 2));
}
```

I cannot find the issue. Is this because of static method? kindly help. I'm using online java compiler from tutorialspoint.

Answer (score 1):

In recursion, for this part of the code:

```
return cost[m][n] + 
        min(minCost(cost, m-1, n-1),
            minCost(cost, m-1, n),
            minCost(cost, m, n-1) );
```

When you do `return 0;` then for the first minCost recursion call the value returned is 0. Since you are checking the min, 0 is always min compared to other minCost recusrion calls, even if they return 1. Hence, for the min function to determine the correct min value of the three minCost calls, you would need to return `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for your exit strategy. Similarly, if you return negative (-1/-2, etc), this will become your min value for your min function.

Hope this explains !